# Using Jquery each loop to stop at intervals

Tags: jquery, dom, append

I have a grid of list items (about 40 `li`s), each containing an image like so:

```
<ul id="grid">
    <li><img src="images/source.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/source.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to use jQuery to insert a new list item after the 8th, 14th, and 23rd list item (or any series of arbitrary numbers).

The new list items already exist in the DOM within a different unordered list like so:

```
<ul id="toBeAppended">
    <li class="dataBlock d0">
            <a href="#dataDummy" class="fancybox">
               <div>
                   <h3>44<span>%</span></h3>
                   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
               </div>
            </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

This unordered list is hidden. I would like to use jQuery to grab `li.d0` and insert it after the 8th list item from above, then grab the next list item in `#toBeAppended` and insert that after the 14th line, and so on.

I am guessing I would store the numbers I want to insert a new list item after into an array like so:

```
var splashArray = [8,14,23];
$("grid li").each(function(i){
 //not sure what to do here in order to stop the the loop at each interval
  i++
});
```

How would I go about doing this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looping over the li's, loop over the array.

```
var $lis = $("#grid li");
var $newlis = $("#toBeAppended li");
$.each([8,14,23],function(i,val){
    $lis.eq(val).after($newlis.eq(i));
});
```

Comment: this is a great start, but I think I also need to group all of the list items inside toBeAppended into an array so I can place each one sequentially after each val interval....any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can't you just replace `.doSomething()` above with `.after("<li>somcontent</li>")`? I'll edit for a more complete sample

Comment: With the edit, the first new li will be placed after 8, 2nd after 14, and 3rd after 23.

Comment: It is not placing the new li in their correct positions, but rather all three would be in a row starting with the 8th list item. It seems like it is only looking for the first number in the array. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: Yes, it wasnt working inside of a callback, but it does work inside of a window.load function. Thanks!